# Redirection to homepage via spring security rest plugin login api

Tags: grails-plugin

How to redirect to homepage from /api/login url as it has predefined response in spring security rest plugin 1.5.4 in grails ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default spring security login end point as below,
open **Config.groovy** file and add the following line in that file,

```
//spring security rest login end point
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = "/PATH_TO_HOME_PAGE"
```

Restart your grails application after change.